# Phalcon blank screen on debian

Tags: php, debian, phalcon, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my first app but having a lot of trouble. I'm on digital ocean and got

`Phalcon` installed on `Debian 7.0`

PHP Version: `5.4.4-14+deb7u12`

I have done some manual tracing so far and it seems that

```
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

returns an empty string, and no errors appear in the error logs or any exceptions thrown.

I printed after this echo and it worked fine, not sure what else I can do to find out why it's not working, it works on my local machine, but I am developing on a mac.

Edit:

I've gotten a little farther and there was a permissions issue with the folders that Phalcon should be able to write to, which are my view folder, my cache folder, etc...

but now getting the following:

```
Warning: Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt\Compiler::compileFile(../app/compiled-templates/%%var%%www%%kiwisoft.co.uk%%releases%%20140722081542%%app%%views%%index%%index.volt.compiled): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/kiwisoft.co.uk/releases/20140722081542/public/index.php on line 33
PhalconException: Volt directory can't be written#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt\Compiler->compileFile('/var/www/kiwiso...', '../app/compiled...', false)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt\Compiler->compile('/var/www/kiwiso...')
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt->render('/var/www/kiwiso...', NULL, true)
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View->_engineRender(Array, 'index/index', true, true, NULL)
#4 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View->render('index', 'index', Array)
#5 /var/www/kiwisoft.co.uk/releases/20140722081542/public/index.php(33): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#6 {main}
```

Help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Has it worked at all? Tested locally right? Show some code...

Comment: Worked perfectly locally. what code would you like to see? as mentioned working fine locally...

Comment: Do you see phalcon in phpinfo() ?

Comment: After fixing my blank screen problem, which was caused by permissions issue on the writeable folders e.g. the compiled-templates path i had set, the logs folder i set and the cache folder (temporarily changed to 777, then after just did proper fix with chown on deployment), I solved the semi blank screen issue by setting git to be case sensitive with the following command:

git config core.ignorecase false
Then changed the folders for each of my views to Ucfirst, as per Marcins example above, FYI for anyone else who experiences this issue!